# Craft Commerce Barclays ePDQ integration

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, payment-methods

Has anyone got this plugin/payment gateway to work?
Having issues with both client and test account details - testing on Craft Commerce 3 and know plugin was developed for Craft Commerce 2 so it is possible therein lies the problem so wondering if anyone has had any joy getting this to work with Craft Commerce 3.

(all submissions are logging a `unknown order/1/s/` - SHASIGN field sent in the transaction request doesn't match the SHASIGN calculated on BarlcayCard end - error)

Cole

Comment: If you try it with Commerce 2 does it work?

Comment: Tried and same error, sadly